# Place window directly behind active window

Tags: macos, swift, cocoa

I want to place a window directly behind the window with the highest window level, and not just the window with the highest level in my app, but for all active apps.

My first idea was to do something like this

```
let activeWindow = //Problems finding a reference to this window.

myWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
activeWindow.makeKeyAndOrderFront(nil)
```

By this way I would get a reference to the active window. Position my window at the top, and then reposition the previous active window on top again. Then all other windows would be positioned under mine.

Do someone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create an instance of `NSWindow` for a window from another app. You can only have window objects for your app's windows.

You can use `orderWindow(_:relativeTo:)` to order a window above or below another window which is identified by its window number. You **can** have the window numbers of windows from other apps. You can use `NSWindow.windowNumbersWithOptions(NSWindowNumberListAllApplications)` to get the window numbers of all windows on the current space from any application. The first window number in the resulting list is the one in front.

I don't recall off-hand if windows which you wouldn't think of as windows — things like the menu bar and Dock, etc. — are included in that list. I think they are.

Also, window levels take precedence over ordering operations like `orderWindow(_:relativeTo:)`. That is, if there are multiple floating windows and your window is a normal, non-floating window, then ordering your window to be immediately behind the front floating window will not put it in front of the other floating windows. All floating windows will always be in front of all normal, non-floating windows. So, if you want your window to be behind the front-most window regardless of its level, you'll have to figure out its level and set your window to have that same level. (Beware: setting your window's level will move it to the front of that level.)

You can also get information about windows using the `CGWindowList` API (e.g. `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo()`). Although it's never been officially documented to my knowledge, the `kCGWindowNumber` key of the description dictionaries returned by that API seem to correspond to Cocoa's window numbers. Some of the other keys may help you filter out things like the menu bar and Dock. Likewise, they can give you the window level of other apps' windows via `kCGWindowLayer`.